# Shared Memory Example for Symbian

Tags: c++, ipc, symbian, shared-memory

I would like to share some memory between two processes. Unfortunately I cannot find any useful examples when using google. The only thing that comes up is how P.I.P.S can be used. But I remember that it could be done in another way, similar to the one of creating of message queues. Would be great if someone could point me in the right direction!

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [`RChunk`](http://www.forum.nokia.com/infocenter/index.jsp?topic=/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/reference/reference-cpp/Kernel_Architecture_2/RChunkClass.html) for plain shared memory. It is a low level, quite efficient mechanism.

Use `RMsgQueue` for message queues, which are on a bit higher abstraction level. See [Using Message Queue](http://www.forum.nokia.com/infocenter/index.jsp?topic=/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/guide/Base-subsystem-guide/e32/MessageQueue/MessageQueueUsing.guide.html) in the SDK help for more.

Comment: thanks, i know how to use message queues. But I wanna know how to use shared memory. There is some possibility to do that in Symbian, but I have forgotten the classnames...

Comment: Have found it now. It is the RChunk class for which I was looking!

Comment: Of course. I edited my answer to contain that option as well so it is more useful for other people looking for the same. (I was a little bit distracted by the words "message queue" in your question, have to admit.)